# How can we control which port(s) will be used to create peer to peer connection in WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have created an application that uses WebRTC and does the screen and audio sharing.
It is purely a front-end application written mainly in javascript.

Now the concern that has been brought to us by users is, they need a list of specific ports that'll be used to create the peer-to-peer connection.

While debugging the application, I see different ports each time for establishing the connection between peers.

Is there any way I can control the port which will be used to create an offer / establish the connection?

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there isn't an easy way to do this today. I would file an issue against [webrtc-nv](https://github.com/w3c/webrtc-nv-use-cases/issues) to get the attention of the standards authors. There was talk of exposing these options on ICETransport, but never saw it go anywhere.

What you could do today is create/destroy peerconnections in a loop until it selected the port you wanted.

Comment: This could be one of the solutions, what about creating our own STUN / TURN server? I have never seen its code available for open source but I have read few articles that said these servers are responsible somehow to get the port number from your system and pass it on. any idea, please?

Comment: @SagarVarma STUN servers allow to know what your public address and port are, they have no influence on what port the peer chooses locally.